# Geolocation install problems

Tags: node.js, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

Trying to install Geolocation in my ionic App
and keep getting the error below,
can anyone help?

> npm ERR! code E405 npm ERR! 405 Method Not Allowed - GET
> https://registry.npmjs.org/@ionic-native%2fgelocation/cordova-plugin-geolocation
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /Users/PetalsTwine/.npm/_logs/2020-07-08T14_39_11_876Z-debug.log

Comment: Please add the code of your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `NPM` is install in your machine. to check npm version run `npm -v` in command propmpt

Then you have to run,

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Then run `npm i geolocation`